# Eagle project wont open, "Error reading file"

Tags: eaglecad

I'm working on a board layout with Eagle.  I tried to open the file today and get a message "error reading file".  No other info besides that and I haven't been able to find anything about this.  It does this with both the .sch and .brd files. Any ideas?

Comment: Version conflict?

Comment: No it's the same version that I was working with it yesterday.

Comment: Are you opening it through Eagle or through the (Windows?) file browser? Do you Dropbox your files at all?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu but I've tried opening it through both Eagle and the file browser.  I think Ubuntu does an automatic backup.  I'll look into that thanks!

Comment: If it is a recent Eagle version, you may open the .brd and .sch files with a text viewer, because they are basically xml text files.  This may give you a clue of what is happening or a way to fix it.

Comment: BTW, eagle also keeps a few backups (exact number is configurable) of the last saves.

Comment: Yes! thanks!  I found the backups that eagle makes and restored it from those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a recent Eagle version, you may open the .brd and .sch files with a text viewer, because they are basically xml text files. This may give you a clue of what is happening or a way to fix it.

BTW, eagle also keeps a few backups (exact number is configurable) of the last saves.

For example, .sch backups will look like this:

```
mysch.s#1
mysch.s#2
...
```

Similary, .brd backups will look like this:

```
mybrd.b#1
mybrd.b#2
```

And even library backups (previous saves) will look as follows:

```
mylbr.l#1
mylbr.l#2
...
```